# how to solve ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 1000, 1) vs (None,)).?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, label, word2vec, word-embedding

```
model = Sequential() 
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, output_dim = 100))
output_dim = DIM

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, output_dim, weights = [embedding_vectors], input_length= 1000,  trainable=False))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y)

model.fit(X_train,  Y_train, validation_split = 0.3, epochs=6)#here the error is coming
```

i tried fixing x and X values and other syntax fixing but, couldn't solved it. Kindly help

Comment: It helps to show in your Q the *full error* that you received, as quoted text, with *all* lines of related 'traceback' info – showing involved files & lines-of-code) (You can edit your question to add this.) Also, while sharing your exact involved code is good, it's also helpful to say something about the overall goal you're trying to achieve – especially if (as here) the code doesn't include *all* info to reproduce the error. (EG: What are your `X`, `y`, & `embedding_vectors`?) Finally, if modeling your code after some example that *does* work, it'd help to mention where your code came from.